# google oauth2 set scope ? cant get email

Tags: php, email, google-plus

Hi im useing googles api oauth2 for a login system and mostly i've got what i want,,, all except the email, after trying all day i have to ask for help. here is my code

```
<?php
$client_key = 'xxxxxxxx49-6gplrhtl5xxxxxxx5gerurei0o.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_secret = 'WLMQxxxxxxxxxxxxxxofyjv11';
$api_key = '9xxxxxxxx0749';
$scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email';
if(!isset($_REQUEST['code'])){
    echo "no Good";
} else {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "code=".$_REQUEST['code']."&client_id=".$client_key."&client_secret=".$client_secret."&redirect_uri=https://localhost/admin/index.php&grant_type=authorization_code");
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close();
    $data = json_decode($data);
    //var_dump($data);
    $access_token = $data->access_token;
    echo $access_token;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=".$access_token);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close();
    $data = json_decode($data);
    echo $data->displayName;
//HERE IS WHERE IM HAVING DRAMA
echo $data->emails->values
    echo "<img src=\"".$data->image->url."\"><br>";
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($data);
    echo '</pre><br>';
}
?>
```

I must be close but .. im stumped

I also tried adding this

```
$scope = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
```

But i had no luck what so ever

Answer (score 1):

Your scope string is wrong there at the top. The easiest one to use is just... "email" ! (as in the word, no quotes).

Make sure all your scopes are valid before signing people in - it looks like you want to use scopes email and profile. These shortened version replace https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email. The longer scopes will still work, but the others you have aren't looked at scopes at all - no scopes have # in them, and all URL form scopes are under googleapis.com/auth.

One other problem - the email will be in an emails array - so it will be $data->emails[0]->value you are looking for (and its worth checking that the type field is "account" too, in case more than one is returned).

You can try it on the API explorer: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get - try selecting the Oauth 2.0 toggle, remove all scopes in there and put email and profile as two custom scopes.